# How to Compare multiple variables at the same time in the C++?

Tags: c++

I'm making Sudoku validater program that checks whether solved sudoku is correct or not, In that program i need to compare multiple variables together to check whether they are equal or not...

I have provided a snippet of code, what i have tried, whether every su[][] has different value or not. I'm not getting expecting result...

I want to make sure that all the values in su[][] are unequal.

How can i achieve the same, what are mistakes in my snippet?

Thanks...

```
for(int i=0 ; i<9 ;++i){ //for checking a entire row

if(!(su[i][0]!=su[i][1]!=su[i][2]!=su[i][3]!=su[i][4]!=su[i][5]!=su[i][6]!=su[i][7]!=su[i][8])){

system("cls");

cout<<"SUDOKU'S SOLUTION IS INCORRECT!!";

exit(0);
```

}
}

Comment: You want to use the logical _and_ operator (`&&`) to combine these comparisons?

Comment: If `su[n]` is a `std::list`, you can use [`std::list::unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/unique/)

Comment: `a!=b` returns a bool (0/1)  which you then feed into another comparison with a  number in the range 1..9, that returns a bool...

Comment: the low-level-c version of this check would be: make a sum( for j from 0 to 8) of 1<<su[i][j] ; if the result is 1022 (? guessing), everything is fine, any other value is wrong

Answer (score 0):

To check for each column uniqueness like that you would have to compare each element to the other ones in a column.

e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < 9; ++k) {
            if (su[i][j] == su[i][k]) {
                system("cls");
                cout << "SUDOKU'S SOLUTION IS INCORRECT!!\n";
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since there are only 8 elements per row this cubic solution shouldn't give you much overhead.

If you had a higher number N of elements you could initialize an array of size N with 0 and transverse the column. For the i-th element in the column you add 1 to that elements position in the array. Then transverse the array. If there's a position whose value is different from 1, it means you have a duplicated value in the column.

e.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    int arr[N] = {0};

    for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        ++arr[su[i][j] - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] != 1) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "SUDOKU'S SOLUTION IS INCORRECT!!\n";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach is way more faster than the first one for high values of N.

The codes above check the uniqueness for each column, you would still have to check for each row.

PS: I have not tested the codes, it may have a bug, but hope you get the idea.

Comment: Why not a linear solution? Just scan all fields, set the respective flag-bit, and then do one compare.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't thought of that bit trick. But if N is > 64 it won't work. You could actually use more than one integer to count the bits. But again, I don't think N will be that high for a sudoku problem. Summing up, you are right.